# Write to google spreadsheet using Python

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, google-docs, google-docs-api

I an wondering is there is a way to write to google spreadsheet using Python.  Found [python-gdata-client](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client) library,  installed it with all dependencies. Using this code below but it is not working

```
import time
import gdata.spreadsheet.service

email = 'email@gmail.com'
password = 'pwd'
weight = '180'
# Find this value in the url with 'key=XXX' and copy XXX below
spreadsheet_key = 'pRoiw3us3wh1FyEip46wYtW'
# All spreadsheets have worksheets. I think worksheet #1 by default always
# has a value of 'od6'
worksheet_id = 'Sheet1'

spr_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
spr_client.email = email
spr_client.password = password
spr_client.source = 'Example Spreadsheet Writing Application'
spr_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

# Prepare the dictionary to write
dict = {}
dict['date'] = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
dict['time'] = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
dict['weight'] = weight
print dict

entry = spr_client.InsertRow(dict, spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id)
if isinstance(entry, gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsList):
  print "Insert row succeeded."
else:
  print "Insert row failed."
```

This is the error is says -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/steve/test.py", line 28, in <module>
    entry = spr_client.InsertRow(dict, spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\spreadsheet\service.py", line 338, in InsertRow
    converter=gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsListFromString)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\service.py", line 1235, in Post
    media_source=media_source, converter=converter)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\service.py", line 1346, in PostOrPut
    redirects_remaining - 1, media_source, converter=converter)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\service.py", line 1328, in PostOrPut
    return converter(result_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdata\spreadsheet\__init__.py", line 376, in SpreadsheetsListFromString
    xml_string)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\atom\__init__.py", line 92, in optional_warn_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\atom\__init__.py", line 126, in CreateClassFromXMLString
    tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)
  File "<string>", line 124, in XML
ParseError: mismatched tag: line 944, column 4
```

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace? There aren't 944 lines of code here

Comment: When you ask questions you should always post full tracebacks.

Comment: Sorry for the I will do it now

Comment: Hi, I tried all the steps mentioned here - gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html . But no success ,, Traceback :Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\steve\get_oauth2_token.py", line 12, in <module> wks = gc.open("siteprice") File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 150, in open raise SpreadsheetNotFound SpreadsheetNotFound

Answer (score 5):

You are using [ClientLogin method](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps?csw=1) which was deprecated since April 20, 2012. It seems, that Google has turned it off on 26 of May, 2015.

Use [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) instead.

Comment: Hi Alik, Do you how to do that, I am bit new to API programming

Comment: @ShekharSamanta I gave you a specific link with examples in Python. Read it and try to implement

Comment: Hi, I tried all the steps mentioned here - http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html  . But no success ,, Traceback :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\steve\get_oauth2_token.py", line 12, in <module>
    wks = gc.open("siteprice")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 150, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound
SpreadsheetNotFound

Comment: @ShekharSamanta so the code works. Make sure `siteprice` spreadsheet exists.

Answer (score 0):

as Alik mentioned above starting from 2015 u need to use oauth2client which you can install by running:

```
pip install oauth2client
```

here is a sample code to login:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


# trying to log in 
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope) # u can download the json file from google's api manager 
client = gspread.authorize(creds) # authorize access

# defining the sheet that we will work on
sheet = client.open('sheetName').sheet1  # getting a sheet to work on
```

I know its been a year now since you asked your question, but i hope i helped some one else.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible using a few packages: gspread, google-api-python-client, oauth2client, tweepy

...for writing a dataframe, use: gspread_dataframe

> pip install gspread, google-api-python-client, oauth2client, tweepy, gspread_dataframe

I wrote a script for tracking twitter sentiment [here on GitHub](https://github.com/aakashhdesai/climate-mood/blob/master/climate_tweets_rake.py).